# Zend Framework post date trouble

Tags: php, zend-framework

There is a system of payment (LiqPay), it sends a post request by payment , I need to accept them, but nothing comes out , `$data` and `$signature = null`. In a separate php file all perfectly accepted , and there is no. If you call the post in `init()` method is accepted , but not my field - this user-id ( in session ), it is only in indexAction.

```
   class User_FeedController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

        protected $bd_usinfo;
        protected $hidefree = false;

    public function indexAction() {
            $data = $_POST['data'];
            $sigrnature = $_POST['signature'];

            $getfeed        = $this->bd_usinfo->getinfobyuserid($this->session['user_id']);
            $this->view->ud = $getfeed;
            $this->view->me = $this->session;

            $this->view->hidefree = false;

            //$this->view->hidefree = true;
            if ((($this->bd_usinfo->isProfessional($this->session['user_id'])) || ( $this->session['role'] == '4'))) {
                $this->view->hidefree = true;
                $this->view->prof     = 1;
            }
            if ($getfeed->feedtime != null) {
                $this->view->hidefree = true;
            }
            if ($this->session['feed'] == 0)
                $this->view->hidefree = true;

            $chng = $this->_request->getParam('chs');
            if ($getfeed->feed != '-1' && $chng == false && $stop != 1) {
                $this->view->alreadyactive = "У вас активирована ";
                if ($getfeed->feedtime != null) {
                    $time_feed = date('n', $getfeed->feedtime - mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m') + 1));
                    // $this->view->alreadyactive .= $feeds[$time_feed];
                    $this->view->alreadyactive .=" платная подписка до " . date('d.m.Y', $getfeed->feedtime);
                }
                else {
                    $this->view->alreadyactive .= " бесплатная подписка";
                }
            }
            $this->view->role     = $this->session['role'];
            $this->bd_config      = new Admin_Model_Config();
            $settings             = $this->bd_config->getSettings();
            $settings             = $settings->toArray();
            $this->view->settings = $settings;
        }
```

Comment: Did you mean third party site will send data to your action and you're not getting posted data, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can set header for access control origin.

Try to set below line in your `indexAction`:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```